# c# regex not enough )'s

Tags: c#, regex

I'm getting the not enough )'s error, but as best I can tell I've got all the )'s in.

line getting error:

```
string pathFriendlyDevId = Regex.Match(device, "VEN.*(?=\\)").ToString().Replace("&", "_");
```

device string getting parsed:

```
string device = "PCI\\VEN_144D&DEV_A804&SUBSYS_A801144D&REV_00\\4&10B60712&0&00EA";
```

the goal here is to get everything from VEN to REV_00.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You have to double escape, which would be \\\\. Or use a verbatim string. `@"Ven.*(?=\\)"`

Comment: the verbatim string did it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out above, using a verbatim string such as `@"VEN.*(?=\\)"` did the trick